# Why arrows in jQuery UI Datepicker make wrong change of the date?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am having standard jQuery UI datepicker like this:

```
$('.text_input').live('focus', function () {
  $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'});
});
```

In the input is already date, e.g. 14.7.2010. When I click the input, datepicker appears and it shows selected date filled in input. However, when I try to navigate using left and right arrows at the top of the datepicker, strange thing happens - it changes date in datepicker to November 1899 or January 1900, depending which arrow I click.

Anybody has any idea why is this happening ? And how to fix it ? I am using jQuery UI 1.8.14 and jQuery 1.4.2.

Comment: Can you please make a quick jsFiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't destroy it. :)

```
$('.text_input').live('focus', function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was easy ;-) I thought that when I am using live() I should destroy the previous datepicker, but your suggestion works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize/create/assing datepicker every time an input gets focus. You can just assign it when dom is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text_input').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });
});
```

Comment: I need to use live() for my scenario.